# Virtual Dom is Late in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have like this code.

```js
<template>
  <div ref="nodesData">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in nodes" :key="index" :id="item.id">
      {{ item.id }}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ result.id || '*' }} - this is id
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const nodesData = ref(null)
const nodes = ref([])
const result = ref('')

onMounted(() => {
  nodes.value.push({
    id: 'test-id',
  })

  // No Problem
  setTimeout(() => {
    result.value = nodesData.value.querySelector(`#${nodes.value[0].id}`)
  }, 1000)
})
</script>
```

this code works fine. But I dont want to use `setTimeout`.

```js
onMounted(() => {
  nodes.value.push({
    id: 'test-id',
  })
  
  // Error
  result.value = nodesData.value.querySelector(`#${nodes.value[0].id}`)
})
```

But this code occur error. Error is

> Uncaught TypeError: nodesData.value is null

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: why would you need to querySelect to get the value? It's an anti-pattern to directly access DOM in this way to get the information that is already available in your `nodes` object. ``nodesData.value.querySelector(`#${nodes.value[0].id}`).id`` is literally the same value as `nodes.value[0].id`

Comment: actually this is not my real problem. it is about sync with real operation and virtual dom operations. this is just an example for my problem. @yoduh

Comment: I solve it by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77895164/14761370) @yoduh

Comment: nextTick has it's uses and does provide a workaround for the issue, although for the specific example you gave there is a much better solution.  Hopefully your real operation is not a similar anti-pattern.  If not, then all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is that you're trying to access the DOM element referenced by nodesData right after updating the reactive data in nodes, but the DOM has not been updated yet to reflect these changes. Vue updates the DOM asynchronously, so the elements you're trying to access do not exist at the time you're trying to access them.

To solve this without using setTimeout, you can use Vue's nextTick function. nextTick allows you to perform actions after the next DOM update cycle, ensuring that the DOM has been updated.

Here's how you can use nextTick in your script setup:

```js
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, nextTick } from 'vue'

const nodesData = ref(null)
const nodes = ref([])
const result = ref('')

onMounted(() => {
  nodes.value.push({
    id: 'test-id',
  })

  nextTick(() => {
    result.value = nodesData.value.querySelector(`#${nodes.value[0].id}`)
  })
})
</script>
```

By using nextTick, you wait until Vue has updated the DOM with the new data before trying to query it, which should resolve the error you're encountering.

Comment: As you've already been made aware on other answers you've deleted, use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic.